# Чем отличаются по смыслу слова "покатый" и "пологий"?

Tags: лексика, синонимы, антонимы

Словом "покатый" можно описывать и нос, и холм, а можно ли нос словом "пологий"?

"Покатый" - всегда выпуклый, или вогнутая форма также может считаться "покатой"?

Answer (score 1):

Да, эти слова синонимы.

**Покатый**

Снижающийся постепенно; пологий.

**Пологий**

Понижающийся постепенно и незаметно; покатый.

**Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.**

Однако о носе говорить покатый или пологий не принято.

В словаре эпитетов даются такие определения.

**О форме, внешнем виде.**

Античный, буграстый (простореч.), вздернутый, вислый, висячий, вогнутый, восточный, вострый (простореч.), горбатый, (с) горбинкой, греческий, грушеобразный, дряблый, загнутый, задранный (разг.), закругленный, заостренный, картофелиной, картошкой (разг.), классический, клювом, кривой, круглый, крючковатый, крючком, курносый, острый, плоский, правильный, привздернутый, приплюснутый, прямой, пуговицей, пуговичный, пуговкой (разг.), пухлый, расплюснутый, расплющенный, римский, русский, славянский, сплюснутый, сплющенный, толстый, тонкий, тупой, уточкой (разг.), хищный, хрящеватый, широкий, шишкастый (простореч.), шишковатый, эллинский.

Comment: Лоб бывает покатым. И пологим, соответственно?

Comment: Да, лоб бывает и покатым и пологим. Что и отражено в словаре.